# How to use ViewBag within Html.Raw?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have code as folows:

```
@Html.Raw("<html lang='@ViewBag.locale' dir='@ViewBag.direction'>")
```

However, this would directly interpret as the string @ViewBag.locale instead of its value.

What is the proper way of doing this, and why do we want to use @Html.Raw instead of actual HTML markup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
@Html.Raw("<html lang=\"" + ViewBag.locale + "\" dir=\"" + ViewBag.direction + "\">")
```

Although it think this looks better:

```
<html lang="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.locale)" dir="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.direction)">
```

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why you need to use Html.Raw here. Maybe if you show more than that one line of code it might make sense, but I doubt it. You'd be better off with simply

```
<html lang="@ViewBag.locale" dir="@ViewBag.direction">
```

Otherwise, if you figure out why you need to use Html.Raw, then you can always go with jao's answer.